# Linux All Output to a File

Tags: linux, pipe, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

Is there any way to tell Linux system put all output(stdout,stderr) to a file?
With out using redirection, pipe or modification the how scrips get called.

Just tell the Linux use a file for output.

for example:
script test1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testing 123 "
```

If i run it like "./test1.sh" (with out redirection or pipe) 
i'd like to see "Testing 123" in a file (/tmp/linux_output)

Problem: in the system a binary makes a call to a script and this script call many other scrips. it is not possible to modify each call so If i can modify Linux put "output" to a file i can review the logs.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >file 2>&1
echo "Testing 123 "
```

You can read more about `exec` [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirections-using-exec)

Comment: This is require to modification the scrips. I'm looking regardless of what script or application run put out put to a file not to a console screen

Comment: @FCa, no, this doesn't require modifying the script, because you can do this in an *intermediate* script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the program from a terminal, you can use the command script.
It will open up a sub-shell. Do what you need to do.
It will copy all output to the terminal into a file. When you are done, exit the shell. ^D, or exit.
This does not use redirection or pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your terminal's scrollback buffer to a large number of lines and then see all the output from your commands in the buffer - depending on your terminal window and the options in its menus, there may be an option in there to capture terminal I/O to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement if taken literally is an impractical one, because it is based in a slight misunderstanding.  Fundamentally, to get the output to go in a file, you will have to *change something* to direct it there - which would violate your literal constraint.

But the practical problem is solvable, because unless explicitly counteracted in the child, the output directions configured in a parent process will be *inherited*.  So you only have to setup the redirection once, using either a shell, or a custom launcher program or intermediary.  After that it will be inherited.

So, for example:

`cat > test.sh`

```
#/bin/sh
echo "hello on stdout"
rm nosuchfile
./test2.sh
```

And a child script for it to call

`cat > test2.sh`

```
#/bin/sh
echo "hello on stdout from script 2"
rm thisfileisnteither
./nonexistantscript.sh
```

Run the first script redirecting both stdout and stderr (bash version - and you can do this in many ways such as by writing a C program that redirects its outputs then exec()'s your real program)

`./test.sh &> logfile`

Now examine the file and see results from stdout and stderr of both parent *and child*.

`cat logfile`

```
hello on stdout
rm: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
hello on stdout from script 2
rm: thisfileisnteither: No such file or directory
./test2.sh: line 4: ./nonexistantscript.sh: No such file or directory
```

Of course if you really dislike this, you can always always modify the kernel - but again, that is changing *something* (and a very ungainly solution too).